# What options do I have to record/share VS Recorder Battles in Pokemon X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, recording

I have a few Pokémon battle videos I'd like to share with friends, most of which live out of town so it isn't as simple as passing around the 3DS.

I know if some of my friends have Pokemon X/Y, I can share the video code (the one that looks like XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX), which someone else enters in their Vs. Recorder to view it. However most of them either don't have Pokemon X/Y yet, or haven't gotten to the point where they unlock the VS Recorder in order to watch them.

I tried logging into the [Global Link](http://3ds.pokemon-gl.com/) to see if I could access the video there, but every time I do it seems to be down for maintenance. Not to mention the [Bulbapedia Entry](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Global_Link#Generation_VI) for the Global Link isn't very descriptive, however it does say that the article is incomplete pending a 'future event', which I assume is the release of the PokéBank on December 27th.

I've also considered buying a [Capture Card](http://3dscapture.com/) mod, however this is a very expensive option, and I'm not really willing to send away my 3DS to have it modded.

The only other option I know of is to record them manually using a video camera. However, every cam-video I've seen online, or tried to record myself has either been too low quality to discern much, or too small in terms of screen size that you don't catch much of the battle anyway.

So in summary:

Is there a way I can give my friends access to the battle videos? Is there a VS Recorder Battle Viewer on the Internet (that takes the video code) or something similar?

If not, what other options do I have, other than recording it using a camera?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. You could use some sort of 3DS gameplay recorder but that is pretty extensive. If you can't lend them your game or just show them the video on your own system then I don't think there is much you can do

Comment: @Kecoey - unfortunately she lives 12 hours away in Melbourne. She loves watching the battles shoutcasters put up online, but doesn't have the money at the moment to fork out for a 3DS/game herself.

Comment: I think you mentioned the key one in your post. The Capture Card, its the way most twitch streamers of pokemon do. But as stated its expensive and dose result in owning a second ds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with these files is that they won't save it as a video but as a set of commands (Pokemon A attacks Pokemon B etc.) so you can't play these files on your computer except there would be a PC software that understands these commands and renders them. You could use an DS emulator and copy your save from your SD card to the virtual SD card of the emulator, then record the output with a screen capture software and send these videos to your friends.

Comment: Interesting. I'd need to get a save file on the emulator up to the point where I unlock the VS Recorder of course- as the actual save game is still saved to the cartridge. I'll have to give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Do you not have a camera or even a cellphone? I mean if you mounted a video recording device well enough I'm sure you could get at least watchable material. And if you don't, maybe buying say a cheap $50.00 camera with a $10.00 tripod is your best bet. Or if you plan take pictures in the future maybe you could invest a bit more than that in a camera/camcorder. However if you're on an extremely tight budget, I'm fairly sure one of your close friends has a decent video recording device you could borrow. Also check your schools tech wing as most schools(At least the ones around me) allow you to rent really decent cameras that are definatly good enough for what you need it for and that option is free. Then simply plop it on youtube. This option may sound cheap but I've seen some pretty good quality nds/gba videos on youtube that were captured by a handheld devices.

Good luck and Merry Christmas

Comment: I do have a camera (a good one too, although lacking a tripod), however I'm looking for a more elegant solution than that. I was hoping that it would be as simple as my friends putting in the video codes on some 'watch Pokemon' Global Link subsite (as I'm only really interested in the Pokemon videos). I've also considered buying a [capture card](http://3dscapture.com/) and hosting on Youtube, although they're very expensive for what I want. In summary, camera is too low quality on the 3DS's small screen, capture cards are too expensive, looking for a middle ground. thanks anyway, Merry Xmas

Comment: Too bad I couldn't get, good luck